# How is object identified in the Spring Boot Cache sample

Tags: spring-boot, caching

I was just looking at the SpringBoot-Cache-sample (https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) and am wondering how the cache Book objects are detected.

The objects to be retrieved are intantiated by the class "Book" with the contructor:

> ```
> private String isbn;
> private String title;
>
> public Book(String isbn, String title) {
>     this.isbn = isbn;
>     this.title = title;
> }
>  @Override
>  public String toString() {
>      return "Book{" + "isbn='" + isbn + '\'' + ", title='" + title + '\'' + '}';
> }
> ```

The class maintaining these objects look like this:

> ```
> @Override
> @Cacheable("books")
> public Book getByIsbn(String isbn) {
>     simulateSlowService();
>     return new Book(isbn, "Some book");
> }
> ```

Each object is "new". It seems there is a wrapper which internally stacks the return values with the method argument as key. And when called again the stack is searched before really running the method.

Do I interpret this right?

But how can I get rid of no longer wanted objects then? Do I need to reinstantiate the class holding the method with the @Cacheable("books") - annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I interpreted it right. Could have looked at the JavaDoc before. Sorry.